# In Pyside, why does emiting an integer > 0x7FFFFFFF result in "OverflowError" after the signal is processed?

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyside

I'm attempting to use signals/slots with large integers ranging from 0 - 2^32-1. I've discovered something a little weird -- once I emit > 7FFFFFFF boundary, I get OverflowError exceptions thrown *after* the slot is run. I might expect this kind of overflow if I or QT were explicitly using a signed 32 bit integer in another language like C or C++--as we all know 0x80000000 wraps back to -2^31 in 2s complement notation. In python though, its just 2^32 without wrapping. My assumption when writing the code though was that this is python and that the built-in int can grow very large (maybe arbitrarilly so?) and that I don't explicitly need to define something as 32 or 64 bit or signed/unsigned. It would all just work.

The code below demonstrates what I'm seeing (Python 2.7.2 (64 bit), Pyside 1.1.0, Windows 7)

```
from PySide.QtCore import *

@Slot(int)
def say(i):
    print "Say %i" % i

class Communicate(QObject):
    speak = Signal(int)

someone = Communicate()
someone.speak.connect(say)
someone.speak.emit(0x7FFFFFFF) #works fine
someone.speak.emit(0x80000000) #OverflowError after slot "say" runs
say(0x80000000)                #works fine
```

The exact output is:

```
Say 2147483647
Say -2147483648
OverflowError
Say 2147483648
```

1. Why does Qt seem to treat the signals/slots of type integer as if its dealing with signed 32 bit integers and not python built-in ints?
2. If this is a restriction of Qt, what can I do to mark the int as unsigned or make sure QT can deal with integers > 0x7FFFFFFF?

Comment: "we all know 0x80000000 wraps back to -1" - i don't think it changes anything, but 0xfffffffff is -1 and 0x80000000 is the largest negative 32 bit integer in 2s complement.

Comment: @andrewcooke you are correct, I fixed the question.

Comment: Obviously Qt makes assumptions that don't fit for Python.

Comment: Also, in Python, 0x80000000 *doesn't* wrap back around to negative numbers, not even at the C level.

Comment: It seems to me it's saying "Don't do that!"  Is there a reason why you need to use such values?  You're simply begging for trouble in any complex environment, especially one with multiple languages involved.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm analyzing C++ performance data compiled into gobs of csv files. The integer value I'm emitting is the address of the currently selected C++ function in the performance data. The address is the best way to uniquely identify the function. This approach works fine, except for this problem.

Comment: @HotLicks Why am I begging for trouble? I'm begging for it to work... or at the very least begging for a link to some documentation that says why I shouldn't do that.

Comment: Qt's default 4-byte integer (`int`) is signed.  I'm unfamiliar with Python, but I gather that it implements unlimited-length integers, and it considers `0x8000000` to be a positive value.  When that positive value is converted to a 4-byte signed integer, there will be an overflow, because that value simply does not fit into a signed 4-byte value.

Comment: @HotLicks thats fine and I can understand that. But as a user of pyside, I can still complain that it doesn't play well with python :)

Comment: Of course, you could always declare the Qt parm `unsigned int`, and then the conversion should be OK.

Comment: @HotLicks - why couldn't you just have said that at the start?

Comment: The OP didn't ask.  He wanted to know why he was getting an exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm mostly a PyQt user, but I believe the behavior is similar. `int` in signal definition is mapped to 4-byte integer (as Qt understands an `int`).

One possible solution is to force the signal to emit a Python object. This works:

```
class Communicate(QObject):
    speak = Signal(object)
```

But be aware that, if you connect this signal to a slot that expects a Qt's version of `int` (for example `QtGui.QSpinBox.setMaximum`) you'll see the same behavior. Other than that, using this signal purely on the Python side should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link saying int in signal definition is tied to QT's (or C++'s) notion of an int and not to pythons?

Comment: @DougT. : PyQt does it [that way](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html). Specifically: _"When a signal is emitted then any arguments are converted to C++ types if possible."_ And [PySide says](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/Signal.html), it implements the same interface. `int` has a direct C++ representation.

Comment: Additional documentation, all the examples in new-style signals and slots point at "int" meaning C integer
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide